# QGIS Geometry Generator Line Type

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry-generator

I am trying to create a line style for a **multiline geometry**. I am hoping to create a linetype which looks like the following
[image]

The Points are not an issue, its the line/lines entering and exiting at the nodes. I was looking to use the Geometry Generator to solve the issue, by creating a buffer, based on the midpoint of each section of the multiline geometry, less the length of the start line and end line and using dissolve to create the line.

**The dataset is a PostGIS vector dataset, I cant duplicate or break the lines into individual lines.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following expression together with geometry generator. Use Linestring as geometry type.

```
intersection(buffer(nodes_to_points( $geometry),2000),$geometry)
```

Adjust the buffer distance to your needs.

[image]

*tested in QGIS 3.6*

Comment: Well done. I was working on a similar answer but I couldn't find the function `nodes_to_points()` because I was searching for "vertex" instead of "note" in the expression builder. So my method required exporting the vertices as a separate layer.

Comment: MrXsquared, Thank you very much for this, much appreciated!!